# Triggering a Google Analytics Event on Form Submit

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to trigger a Google Analytics event when the user submits a form that is in a block.

My goal is to track conversions when the user signs up to the [Campaigner](http://www.campaigner.com) contacts manager and email list software.

I'm using the Google Analytics module  (7.x-2.0) and the following code

```
<input name="SubmitButton" value="Submit" id="SubmitButton" class="btnStyle"   style="background-color:#77738e;color:white" type="submit" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Form Submit','Campaigner Subscribe','EJ Now',1,false]);">
```

That gives me an error in Firebug: "ReferenceError: _gaq is not defined". So I tried adding `var _gaq = _gaq || [];` to the onClick function.  That removes the error, but the event does not show up in Google Analytics Real Time.

Is the _gaq object not properly registered by the Google Analytics module?

[This is my website](http://www.energyjustice.net)  You can test the form using a fake email.  The form is Energy Justice Now and is in the top of the right column.

**Update:**
I have since implemented the Google Analytics Event Tracker module and the example module that comes with it. I see events being triggered in Firebug console, but I do not see them in Google Analytics (even after waiting 12 hours).

The Google Analytics module appears to be operating fine and I get analytic results for the website.  It is just that I cannot get the event tracker to work.

Comment: Is your button created using Form API? Webform? Contact module? Something else? Or hacked directly into HTML? In that last case, don't expect it to work with Drupal modules, unless you know what you are doing really, really well.

Comment: The button is created using Campaigner.  I'm trying to track the page flow of who signs up to Campaigner email lists using Google Analytics Conversions or Events.

Comment: Edit it into your question. With links to appropriate project pages. For now I don't know which "Campaigner" you're using... there are quite lot things with that name, no surprise because it's a word found in dictionaries.

Comment: Maybe I need to use the Google Analytics Event Tracker module.

Comment: I haven't got Google Analytics Event Tracker to work. Even the default event in the example module (clicking on the logo) shows an action in Firebug console, but it doesn't show up in Google Analytics Real Time.

Comment: So you just took a piece of code from http://www.campaigner.com/ and pasted it to your theme? Block? Content? Or what exactly you did? Sorry, but I don't believe you can expect we will debug and reverse-engineer your site for you, if you want people here to know, tell.